# How to express the following summation in matrix form?

Tags: statistics, summation, summation-method

Given data X and Y in matrix form, consider estimating  by minimizing the follwing:

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i -x_i^T )^2 + \sum_{j = 1}^p (_j)^2   $$

where *p* is the dimension of X (number of variables). Find the estimate of B̂ in matrix form.

Comment: Looks like a tough one for sure. Have you tried working through the standard technique for characterizing stationary points? Best to describe what you’ve tried so far, otherwise some might think you haven’t tried at all.

Comment: Very true. I started by expanding the brackets such that I got: yi'*yi + xi*B'*xi etc... but I don't think that they may be the right path as typically our teacher has only ever shown us e'e = (y - xb^)'(y - xb^), which I modeled my response after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(y-\underbrace{X}_{n\times p}\,\beta)^T\underbrace{(y-X\beta)}_{n \times 1}+\beta^T\underbrace{\beta}_{p \times 1}$$
To minimize, we first expand it
$$y^Ty-y^TX\beta-\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta+\beta^T\beta= \\ =y^Ty-2\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta+\beta^T\beta$$
we take the derivative with respect to $\beta$, then set it to $0$:
$$-2X^Ty+2X^TX\beta+2\beta=0$$
$$\beta=(X^TX+I_p)^{-1}X^Ty$$